# Two Targets One Project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have duplicated the target in my project in Xcode 5 so that I can build a lite version of my app.  How do I add a compiler flag to the lite target in my app so I can use #ifdef to restrict features in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Select your target, then add a macro under Build Settings -> Preprocessor Macros.